# Waiting for firebase response before continuing loop

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I'm building an app like uber and I would like to send a trip request to drivers in my database one by one and wait for the driver's response before sending the request to the next driver(if the trip is rejected) or ending the loop(if the trip is accepted).

I have tried to use a for loop on all the drivers gotten from the database and send the request then listen but it doesn't give the desired result. Instead, it sends the request to ALL drivers.

```
   sendTripRequest(request){
    this.rejecters = [];
    // var i = 0;
    // var inProgress = false;
    Object.keys(this.allDrivers).forEach((key)=>{
      // put all drivers into an array
      this.allDriversAray.push(this.allDrivers[key])
    })

    // sort all drivers by distance and put in another array
    this.sortedDriversAray = this.applyHaversine(this.allDriversAray,request.originLat,request.originLng);
    this.sortedDriversAray.sort((locationA,locationB)=>{
      return locationA.distance - locationB.distance;
    });
    // send request to drivers starting from closest
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      console.log('sorted array is ');
      console.log(this.sortedDriversAray);

        for(let i = 0;i<this.sortedDriversAray.length;i++){  
          console.log('handling driver: '+this.sortedDriversAray[i].id);

          // while(inProgress);  
          // inProgress = true;   

          if(this.sortedDriversAray[i].availability === true && this.rejecters.indexOf(this.sortedDriversAray[i]) <= -1 && this.sortedDriversAray[i].request == undefined){
            console.log('driver '+this.sortedDriversAray[i].id + ' is available and hasnt rejected,sending request')

                this.driversRef.child(`${this.sortedDriversAray[i].id}`).update({ request: request }).then(()=>{
                  // watch driver and update changes
                  this.driversRef.child(`${this.sortedDriversAray[i].id}`).on("value",response=>{
                    let driverResponse = response.val().request
                    if(driverResponse == undefined){
                      console.log('driver '+this.sortedDriversAray[i].id+' just rejected,adding him to array');
                      this.rejecters.push(this.sortedDriversAray[i].id);
                      console.log(this.rejecters);
                      // inProgress = false;
                    }else if(driverResponse.accepted == true){
                      console.log('yay! driver '+this.sortedDriversAray[i].id+' just accepted');
                      // this.trackDriver(closestDriver.id)
                      // resolve(true) 
                    }
                  })
                })
            }else{
            console.log('no drivers found')
            this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
            resolve('no driver found')
            }
      }
    })

  }
```

I would like the function to first send to the first driver in the sorted array, wait for his response, if it is rejected(i.e request is deleted and is now undefined), then send to the next driver and if accepted then stop the for-loop...Please help

Answer (score 0):

A for loop won't work because as you have discovered it will just fire them all off.

Instead I think you need a recursive function.

This is just a quick idea, obviously I cannot compile it so I don't know if it works but its just to give you the concept:

```
askNextDriver(sortedDriversAray, i) {
    console.log('handling driver: '+sortedDriversAray[i].id);

    // while(inProgress);  
    // inProgress = true;   

    if(sortedDriversAray[i].availability === true && this.rejecters.indexOf(sortedDriversAray[i]) <= -1 && sortedDriversAray[i].request == undefined){
      console.log('driver '+sortedDriversAray[i].id + ' is available and hasnt rejected,sending request')

          this.driversRef.child(`${sortedDriversAray[i].id}`).update({ request: request }).then(()=>{
            // watch driver and update changes
            this.driversRef.child(`${sortedDriversAray[i].id}`).on("value",response=>{
              let driverResponse = response.val().request
              if(driverResponse == undefined){
                console.log('driver '+sortedDriversAray[i].id+' just rejected,adding him to array');
                this.rejecters.push(sortedDriversAray[i].id);
                console.log(this.rejecters);

                // ASK NEXT DRIVER
                if(i < sortedDriversAray.length) {
                    this.askNextDriver(sortedDriversAray, i++);
                }
                // END ASK NEXT DRIVER

                // inProgress = false;
              }else if(driverResponse.accepted == true){
                console.log('yay! driver '+sortedDriversAray[i].id+' just accepted');
                // this.trackDriver(closestDriver.id)
                // resolve(true) 
              }
            })
          })
      }else{
      console.log('no drivers found')
      this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
      resolve('no driver found')
      }
}
```

So you start it off when you have got your initial list of drivers, and then each time a driver declines, it checks if there are any more drivers and then calls itself:

```
                // ASK NEXT DRIVER
                if(i < sortedDriversAray.length) {
                    this.askNextDriver(sortedDriversAray, i++);
                }
                // END ASK NEXT DRIVER
```